# How to add a texture to one side of a cube without THREE.MultiMaterial to reduce draw calls

Tags: three.js

So lets say theres a cube with 2 materials.I'm using MultiMaterial but maybe thats not the correct approach because its showing 6 draw calls instead of 2. I'm worried about performance when it scales up. 
http://codepen.io/glued/pen/JXmvzm

This is just an example, I know about FaceColors but would like to mix a meshBasicMaterial with another Material, say, with a texture.

```
var greenMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xc4f288 })
var orangeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xf4511e })
var mats = [
  orangeMaterial,
  greenMaterial,
  orangeMaterial,
  orangeMaterial,
  greenMaterial,
  orangeMaterial
]

let box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MultiMaterial( mats ))
```

If i used vertexColors: FaceColors and a texture:
`new MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: FaceColors,  map:someTexture  }))`

how would i designate the texture for a specific face only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by creating a material with a texture and removing the UVs on the geometry faces that i'm not using

[image: texture]

the texture is 128x256, See the codepen as i'm using a 2d canvas to generate

```
texture.repeat.y = 0.5
texture.offset.y = 0.5

let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50)

function assignUvAndColor(geo, i, color = 0x00cbff){
  geo.faceVertexUvs[0][i] = new Array(3).fill(new THREE.Vector2(0, -1))
  geo.faces[i].color.setHex(color)
}

const greenColor = 0xacffd3
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 3, greenColor)
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 2, greenColor)
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 0, greenColor)
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 1, greenColor)
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 4)
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 5)
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 6)
assignUvAndColor(geometry, 7)

let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({  map: texture, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors })
let box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
```

http://codepen.io/glued/pen/grBEmo?editors=0010

[image]

Comment: In your example, try `ctx.strokeStyle = 'orange', or any other color, and see what happens.

Comment: oh no, how do i fix the color bleeding over?

Comment: It is not bleeding over. It is using the UVs you specified: ( 0, 0 ).

Comment: I updated the codepen to fix the issue by extending the canvas size to 128x256 and where one half is white and the other is the "graphic", then set the UVs to new THREE.Vector2(0, -1).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

multimaterial will always do N drawcalls where N =  length of its material array
(see [renderer implementation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js))

it does not even try to check whether some of its materials are duplicite in reference - so in your examples you have multimaterial with 6 materials = 6 drawcalls

you will have to change the geometry face material index or abandon using multimaterial and divide your geometry manually